# Direct limit over cofinal subset of a preordered, not directed, set is isomorphic to the original one

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

I have been struggling with this exercise I've been assigned. The difficulty is in the fact that the set of indeces is **not** necessarily directed. Here's the text:

> Let $I$ be a preordered set,
> $\mathbb{M}=(M_i,\mu_{ii'})$ a direct system of right modules over a
> ring $R$, and $(M,\mu_i)$ the direct limit of $\mathbb{M}$. Let
> $J\subseteq I$ be a *cofinal* subset of $I$, that is, a subset of
> $I$ such that for every $i\in I$ there exists $j\in J$ with $i\le j$.
> Let $\mathbb{N} =(N_i,\nu_{jj'})$ be the direct system with $N_j=M_j$ for every $j\in J$ and $\nu_{jj'}=\mu_{jj'}$ for every $j,j'\in J$, $j\le j'$. Let $(N,\nu_i)$ be its direct limit. Show that there exist an isomorphism $\varphi\colon M\to N$ such that $\varphi\mu_j=\nu_j$ for every $j\in J$.

Of course, using the universal property of direct limit I have been able to prove that there exist a (unique) morphism $\psi:N\to M$ such that $\mu_j=\psi\nu_j$. Since $J$ is cofinal, it is easy to see that $\psi$ is surjective. Unfortunately, I haven't managed to prove that it is injective. At this point, I'm not even sure that it is true. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Are you sure $I$ is not supposed to be directed? The claim is false as currently stated.

Comment: @Thorgott I am sure. The professor explicitly said so, modifying the statement in the book, which instead required *I* to be directed. Could you show me a counterexample?

Comment: There is a definition of cofinal which makes the statement true for general $I$, but it is not the definition quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest non-directed and non-discrete poset already furnishes an example: the colimit of $a\leftarrow b\to c$ is a pushout while the colimit of $a\quad c$ is a coproduct,